# Error(5): PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When running the following statement I receive an error using Oracle 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER autoincrement_sm_users_id BEFORE INSERT ON SM_USERS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT sm_users_id.NEXTVAL INTO : new.id FROM dual; END;
```

The error is:

```
Error(5): PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]
```

Comment: create or replace TRIGGER
autoincrement_sm_users_id
BEFORE INSERT ON SM_USERS
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
SELECT sm_users_id.NEXTVAL
INTO : new.id
FROM dual; 
END;

Comment: When you try to compile what? Are you installing the Oracle database?

Comment: I try to share my code :( yes I did

Comment: So you have a database server running and you're compiling something to use it? Is this occurring on the statement you added as a comment?

Comment: there is no problem with database server. yes on this statement

Comment: it is internal error. and I need to fix it not code block

Comment: You may wish to add some information about the database schema as well. I am not sure I can answer the question but providing as much information as possible will help those who can find and solve the issue much faster.

Comment: I have "SM_USERS" table and I created all columns. now I try to apply an auto increment to user_id.

Comment: just tell me pls how can I fix 00801 internal error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER autoincrement_sm_users_id BEFORE INSERT ON SM_USERS FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SELECT sm_users_id.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.id FROM dual; END;
```

Remove the space between the colon (`:`) and `NEW`.

Comment: Second result on Google.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answer above I'd like to note that the same thing could also happen in any pl/sql unit if you copy and paste a code from your test script and forget to remove `&` symbol before a variable.

E.g. your pl/sql unit contains something like

```
...
select value
inlo l_variable
from table
where key = l_key_var;
...
```

You want to execute this piece of code like

```
select value
--inlo l_variable
from table
where key = &l_key_var;
```

And after tasting and debugging you copy this piece back as

```
...
select value
inlo l_variable
from table
where key = &l_key_var;
...
```

Here the `&` symbol will cause «PLS-00801: internal error [ph2csql_strdef_to_diana:bind]».
But, who is «diana» mentioned in the message? :)

Comment: great, you saved me a nighttime